# Facebook Pixel Unable to capture add to cart, purchase events for configurable products in magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, facebook-pixel

We have tried to add the pixel code but the Facebook Pixel is unable to capture add to cart, purchase events for configurable products in magento 2. is there a way to resolve this? As this seems to be impacting our lookalike audience. Thanks in advance